# How to I do this in regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex

I have a java program, and in one part of my code I have to read a string like this, `^s(group1) ^s(group2)` and then return the strings "group1" and "group2" so I used this regexp `\^s\(.*\)` but it returns the whole string.

What's wrong?

Comment: maybe googling a bit would help... :)

Comment: It's that i dont know what to google :/

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/intro.html

Comment: I already googled the basic of them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*` matches `)` so the match doesn't stop at the close parenthesis.  Try `[^\)]*` instead, or `[^\(\)]*` if you want a bit of extra insurance against nested parenthetical groups.

You could also look into using a non-greedy modifier, `.*?`, which would also solve the problem.  Some find that more readable than a negated charset match.

Comment: well the problem with both it's that it just matches the first group http://regexr.com/3a14v

Comment: @GonzaloRizzo, there's a second problem.  please see my edits.

Comment: this should not to be a problem because I didnt wrote ^ y wrote \^ because I want to match the ^ character

Comment: @GonzaloRizzo, Good point.  In that case, I need to see your Java code to diagnose why you're getting one result.

Comment: It has nothing to do with java because regexr.con doasn't give me two groups neither

Comment: @GonzaloRizzo, regexr.com gives two matches with `/\^s\([^)]*\)/g` when I try it.  Notice the `g` modifier on the end.

Comment: Well, I don't know why but in regexr.com I had the global flag disabled and in the java code I tried to used 
`m.find();
System.out.println(m.group(1));
System.out.println(m.group(2));` instred of `while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}`

Comment: @GonzaloRizzo, Try doing `while (m.find)` and grabbing group 1 repeatedly.  If you only have one group in your pattern, then you will only have one group (besides group 0) in your matcher.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract those words with [groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

`\^s\((.*?)\)`

This says to capture anything in between ^s() and can be used like this.

```
String str = "^s(group1) ^s(group2)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\^s\\((.*?)\\)").matcher(str);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
group1
group2
```